# Korean Data Loading in Hive

Tags: linux, hive

I have a requirement of loading a sample data-set into hive table.
The data looks like this: 
**차주사 업체별 한도 제한으로 할인 못함 - 업체별 한도제한 해제요청.**
which seems to be korean.

The file which will get loaded into hadoop, contains 2 columns : 
name and description.(Name field is english).

### Table DDL

Name - String
Description - String

Before loading the data into Hive, i have tried the following things.
1. native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 filename filename1
   (then loading the filename1 into hive).
   the above command converts the characters into utf-8 and the following results 
**\ucc28\uc8fc\uc0ac \uc5c5\uccb4\ubcc4 \ud55c\ub3c4 \uc81c\ud55c\uc73c\ub85c \ud560\uc778 \ubabb\ud568 - \uc5c5\uccb4\ubcc4 \ud55c\ub3c4\uc81c\ud55c \ud574\uc81c\uc694\uccad.**

But upon querying the table I still get the description in utf-8 format and not in korean language.

2. Also tried doing luit conversion on the file before loading luit -c -encoding cjk  ${file_name}_encd
   This is giving different characters and not the expected results.

What should i be doing? Am i missing something. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE homeplus_tmp.test_customers SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='EUC-KU');